# Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to two bases

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I cannot get my head around this question. I have looked through examples in my textbook and online but they don't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(x,y)=(2x-y,x+y)$.

a) Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $B_1=\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$ and $B_2  = \{(-1,2),(1,1)\}$

b) Use the matrix found in part a) to find $T(v)$, where $v=(2,3)$.

Comment: This is a very technical problem. All you need to do in order to solve it is to know the definitions. Do you know what is the definition of the transformation matrix with respect to the bases $B_1, B_2$?

Comment: Everything I know is above.

Comment: Your problem is likely a lack of understanding of what it *really* means to consider a vector space with respect to a specific basis (don't feel bad, I worked in a tutoring center for years, and this is common). Start with a smaller problem: can you find the matrix of that transformation with respect to the usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( <0,1>, <1,0> )? If yes I recommend thoroughly reading everything in your book about bases and re-trying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You have to know that if $P$ is the square matrix with column vectors the coordinates of the vectors in $\mathscr B_1$:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
is the *change of basis matrix* from the standard basis to basis $\mathscr B_1$. Note this matrix is invertible since $\mathscr B_1$ is a basis.

Namely, if $X$ is the (column) matrix of coordinates of a vector $v$ in the standard basis, and $X'$ the matrix of its coordinates in basis $\mathscr B_1$, we have the relation
$$X=PX'.$$

Now let's denote $A$ the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis? This means that if vector $v$ is represented by the column matrix $X$, $T(v)$ is represented by the column vector
$$Y=AX.$$

Similarly, in basis $\mathscr B_1$ $v$ is represented by the matrix $X'$ and $T(v)$ by the matrix $A'X'$.

Rewrite the initial relation:
$$Y=AX\iff PY'=A(PX')\iff Y'=P^{-1}A(PX')=(P^{-1}AP)X'$$
so that the matris of $T$ in basis $\mathscr B_1$ is 
$$A'=P^{-1}AP.$$

Comment: Ok. I don't know if what I did is right but I got.

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1/3&0\\4/3&3\end{pmatrix}$$
Does this seem right?

Comment: I obtain $A'=\begin{pmatrix}3&3\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ (I supposed you're meaning the matrix of $T$ in the second basis).

Comment: I will put down my working:
$T(1,1)=(1,2)$,  

Therefore $(1,2)=a(-1,2)+b(1,1)$

,  $-a+b=1$ and $2a+b=2$

,  $a=1/3$ and $b=4/3$
This is the first column of my T matrix? I repeated the same procedure to get the second column.
Is this not right?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I just  found  I calculated the matrix in basis $\mathscr B_1$. Why do you compute the coordinates of $T(1,1)$ in basis $\mathscr B_2$? You have the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis, by the equations, and you're asked the matrices of $T$ in bases $\mathscr B_1$ and $\mathscr B_2$ respectively.

Comment: I was following a similar question in a tutorial. I see how you got your matrix, but is that only in terms of $B_1$ ? Do we not want to find the matrix in respect to both bases?

Comment: You just have to use this general formula (which has to be known by heart) for each basis. The only thing that changes is the value of the matrix $P$.